# How do you generate a new self sign certificate for use with Landscape in Ubuntu 18.04LTS?

Tags: landscape

How do you generate a new self sign certificate for use with Landscape in Ubuntu 18.04LTS?

When i run this `$ /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -signreq`

I get this error:
`Unknown arg "-signreq"
Use -help for help.`

From link 
https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/SSL

I'm following the steps in order on a ubuntu 18.04LTS server. Any idea what is wrong?

Docs are wrong for "Signing your certificate". Change:

```
$ /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -signreq

# TO

$ /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -sign
```

But even with that i can't get it to work, and the Landscape documentation on this has not been updated since 2012. Can someone help with the following?

**How do you create a self signed certificate ubnuntu 18.04LTS for use in Landscape?** I tried following the docs at https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/SSL and it does not work. I can't sign for more than 365 days even though i changed days in the CA.pl to 10950. When registering a new client i still get

`certificate subject name (ctrl-server1) does not match target host name 'tst.ctrl-server1.com'` even though i re-generated another certificate after changing apache site

Comment: You should reach out to Canonical/Landscape about this, we can't update Canonical's documentation from here.